# UITableView custom cell not showing core data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I had the table cells showing the data correctly, but then made a custom cell and class so that I would have more control over the layout...but I can't get my custom cell to show the data..it just shows the labels with their placeholder text...what am I missing?

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.results.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellResults";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    ResultsCell *resultscell = (ResultsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSManagedObject *result = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *eventDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self trialDate]];

    // formatting
    resultscell.labelEventDesc.numberOfLines = 0;

    //  populate the cells
    [resultscell.labelEventDesc setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"eventdesc"]]];
    [resultscell.labelWeeksOut setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"weeksout"]]];
    [resultscell.labelEventDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventDate]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating 2 different cell instances (`cell` and `resultscell`), configuring one and returning the other. So your custom class instance is never used for anything really.

Remove:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and change `return cell;` to `return resultscell;`.

Comment: Spot on!  Amazing how you can look at a piece of code forever and all it takes is another set of eyes to see something obvious.  Many thanks...works perfect.